# ¿Cómo ejecutar un script TSQL automáticamente después de apagar y encender un servidor?

Tags: sql, servidor, tsql

Tengo un problema en el trabajo, específicamente un servidor tiende a a reiniciarse en la madrugada y el problema es que al reiniciarse el servicio de SQL Server los permisos y roles de los usuarios en una base temporal se eliminan. Tengo que ejecutar un *script* como el del siguiente ejemplo cada vez que eso sucede:

---

```
USE [prueba]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'user'
GO

GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::dbo.Products TO user;
GO

GRANT INSERT ON OBJECT::dbo.Products TO user;  
GO

GRANT UPDATE ON OBJECT::dbo.Products TO user;  
GO

GRANT DELETE ON OBJECT::dbo.Products TO user;  
GO
```

---

Necesito saber cómo ejecutar este *script* de forma automática una vez que se encienda el servidor y se inicie el servicio de SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que hay que hacer es intentar correr el *script* (este *script* ya debe contener toda la definición de lo pusiste en tu pregunta) desde la línea de comandos, para eso existe el comando `sqlcmd`:

```
sqlcmd -U NombreUsuario -P Contraseña -S Servidor -d BaseDeDatos -­i "c:\MiScript.sql"
```

Donde la definición de los parámetros<sup>1</sup> es:

> -­U: Nombre del usuario que accede a la base de datos ­-P: Contraseña de la cuenta
>
> -S: Nombre del servidor de base de datos
>
> -d: Nombre de la base de datos
>
> -i: Ruta donde se encuentra el script que se va a ejecutar

<sub>*1. Toma en cuenta que los parámetros son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas. La lista completa de los parámetros y su definición la puedes encontrar en la página de la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility).*</sub>

Siguiente paso es guardar esa línea (`sqlcmd -U NombreUsuario -P Contraseña -S Servidor -d BaseDeDatos ­i "c:\MiScript.sql"`) en un archivo `.bat`, por ejemplo, pongamos **`c:\TareaAutomatica.bat`**

Ahora, directamente en el servidor, vamos a iniciar la aplicación **`Task Scheduler`** y haremos lo siguiente:

1. Clic derecho a **`Task Scheduler (local)`** y luego en **`Create Basic Task`**
2. Sección **`Create Basic Task`** dale el nombre que desees
3. Sección **`Trigger`** selecciona `When the computer starts`
4. Sección **`Action`** selecciona `Start a Program`
5. Sección **`Start a Program`** selecciona la ruta de archivo `TareaAutomatica.bat`
6. Sección **`Finish`** finalizar la creación de la tarea.

Con esto, cada que se reinicie tu servidor se ejecutará el archivo `TareaAutomatica.bat` que a su vez, ejecutará un *script* de base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

De entrada me parece que tratar de solucionar el problema de los permisos con la ejecución de un script está enmascarando dos problemas subyacentes:

1. ¿Por qué se reinicia el servidor? Esto puede indicar que hay otros problemas, inclusive de hardware que pueden resultar en una eventual pérdida de datos.
2. ¿Por qué se depende de permisos en una base de datos temporal? Sería mejor formalizar las tablas en una base de datos no temporal.

Si se solucionan estos problemas ya no hay necesidad de agregar más complejidad al sistema y otro punto de posible fallo que se debe monitorear y tener en cuenta.

En caso de que se asuma este riesgo y se opte por hacer más complejo el sistema, puedes usar un disparador (trigger) de inicio de sesión (logon) para el usuario en cuestión que verifique si tiene el rol requerido y los permisos al inicio de sesión y los agregue en caso contrario.

La respuesta de @Flxtr me parece hace aún más complejo el sistema y agrega otra dependencia (Task Scheduler), inclusive es probable que cuando se ejecute la tarea aún no termine de iniciar SQL Server y no esté disponible por lo que habría que agregar más complejidad para intentar detectar si ya está disponible el servicio de SQL Server y la base de datos está disponible.